# Ionic Framework - 'nav' undefined when trying to push pages

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to make an Android app using Ionic framework. I implemented a side menu and when I try to push pages from the side menu, I get an error in the console saying:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

**app.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, ionicBootstrap, Platform, MenuController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';

import { HomePage } from './pages/home/home';
import {AppSettingsPage} from "./pages/app-settings/app-settings";
import {TabsPage} from "./pages/tabs/tabs";
import {ReserveRoomPage} from "./pages/reserve-room/reserve-room";
import {ConfirmedReservationsPage} from "./pages/confirmed-reservations/confirmed-reservations";


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  providers: [NavController]
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild('nav') nav: NavController;
  private rootPage: any;
  private pages: any[];
  private icon = 'cog';

  constructor(private platform: Platform, private menu: MenuController,
  private modalCtrl: ModalController) {
  this.menu = menu;
    this.pages = [
      {title: 'Home', component: HomePage, icon: 'home'},
      {title: 'Settings', component: AppSettingsPage, icon: 'settings'},
      {title: 'Reserve Room', component: ReserveRoomPage, icon: 'add'},
      {title: 'My Reservations', component: ConfirmedReservationsPage, icon: 'book'},
    ];
    this.rootPage = TabsPage;

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }

  openPage(page){
    this.menu.close();
    this.nav.push(page.component);
  }

}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

**app.html**

```
<ion-menu [content] = "content">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title><strong>Giman</strong>.lk</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        <ion-icon name="{{ p.icon }}"></ion-icon> {{ p.title }}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage" #content swipe-back-enabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

**app-settings.ts** (Example of a page I want to push)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/app-settings/app-settings.html',
})
export class AppSettingsPage {

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private view: ViewController) {

  }
  goBack(){
    this.view.dismiss();
  }

}
```

(I imported ModalController because I wanted to preview my App UI flow and because push didn't work, I used each page as a modal just for preview purposes. For the final app, I need push and pop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `@ViewChild` to `NavController` but to `Nav`.

```
import { Nav } from 'ionic-angular';

.....

@Component({
  templateUrl: "build/app.html" //no need for the provider
})

class MyApp{
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav; //remove the 'id' from the HTML, it will find the ion-nav tag
  ....
  someFunction(){
    this.nav.push(YourComponent);
    //or
    this.nav.setRoot(YourComponent); 
  }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks a lot. Any reason you set it to `Nav` and not `NavController`?

Comment: @user9492428 tbh I'm not sure, even the [ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/#navigating-from-the-root-component) say to use NavController, although when using `ionic generate myapp` they will provide you with the `Nav`. Maybe they will update this

Answer (score 1):

on IONIC 3, 
I used this and it works !!
to call parent nav from childview

```
   var navParent = this.navCtrl.parent.parent as NavController;
   navParent.push('DetailsTabPage')
```